# Improved table structure for querying quarterly spend data

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am looking for advice on most efficient table structure/SQL code for a project I am working on for my company.  I am not a profesional developer so a simpler solution is preferable.

Project Requirements:

I want to create an HTML table that displays aggregate spend by vendor category by fiscal quarter where each of the categories is a link that can be clicked on to expand to get vendor level x business unit level spend.

I already have this up and running.  I built in PHP and MySQL.  However, the queries I run to expand the table are running VERY SLOWLY in some cases.  I want to overhaul my table structure and querying to make the whole process more efficient and flexible.

**Summary of the data that I have**

I get raw data every quarter from every business unit with spend by vendor.  I also have a decoder ring that matches vendor name to vendor category (e.g. starbucks -> restaurant).

**My Current Process**
I roll up  quarterly data into a table called spendfile with the following columns:

- vendorname
- standard_vendor_name (corrects misspells in vendor name, etc.)
- vendor_category
- quarter
- spend

When I a request from a user (for the first time) to see the HTML table with the categories down side and spend by quarter in separate columns I create a temporary table called treetable with the following columns:

- rowlabel (name of category/vendor that appears down side of table)
- spendQ1 (separate column for spend with vendor in every quarter)
- spendQ2
- spendQ3
- spendQ4
- spend...

Note that in order to get this table I need to select all unique vendor categories, then sum spend by quarter for each quarter and finally join the quarterly total spend for each quarter to the category list (so I am doing 5-6 joins, 1 for every time period).

Then I render as html table (fairly straightforward)

When the user clicks on a category to get more detail, I go through a similar process: gettting unique list of vendors, summing spend (this time for all vendors across a particular category) and join all the time periods as separate columns.

The last step is to union the new drilled down data to the treetable table in the right spot (underneath the category all the vendors belong to).

Does anyone have any ideas on better ways to do this?  Does what I am trying to do make sense?

Thanks

Comment: I would love to help you out, but I would need more information. Could you put the queries you are actually using to get the information?

Comment: +1 for a good question, for your vendor spelling correction, and for "decoder ring"

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to offer specific suggestions -- like possible SQL to use -- without knowing more about your schema. Still, I'll try. Here are some general suggestions.

1. try to quantify "very slowly" so you can know whether you're improving things as you put in refinements. Also quantify how much data you're coping with.
2. only use temporary tables if you're absolutely sure you need them. One of the most expensive (=== slow) things that can happen in a DBMS is the writing of data to tables. If you don't need temp tables don't use them.
3. if you can possibly do it, create a single SQL query that generates the correct columns and rows for the table you hope to display in HTML from your raw data.  Then, run that query in a command-line mySQL client and use the EXPLAIN command to have mySQL tell you what it's trying to do. See here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

Here's some more specific suggestions about how that query might work.  Let's say your input table has this schema.

```
vendorname
standard_vendor_name (corrects misspells in vendor name, etc.)
vendor_category (character string)
quarter (integer)
spend  (floating point)
```

Let's say you want as a result, a table with these columns

```
vendor_category
vendor (standardized spelling)
spend_q1
spend_q2
spend_q3
spend_q4
```

I'm sorry to say I don't understand your question about how you're handling vendor names and categories in your output. I assume you're simply showing category then name for each vendor, and ordering by category.

I also don't understand how you're storing the `quarter` in your input table. Let's suppose you're using a numerical format like 20111, 20112, 20113, 20114, 20121, 20122 for 1Q2011 - 2Q2012.

Let's suppose you want to display any four consecutive quarters in your html table, just for grins.

So, here we go.

We need a little subquery to generate the four quarter IDs you need, based on the ID of the most recent quarter you want to display--which you need to provide.

```
SELECT DISTINCT QUARTER
  FROM INFO
 WHERE QUARTER <= ~~~the most recent quarter~~~
 ORDER BY QUARTER DESC
 LIMIT 0,4
```

If you're always starting with the most recent quarter you can simply leave out `WHERE QUARTER <= ~~~the most recent quarter~~~` from this little subquery, and it will pick up the most recent data you have.

Second, we need to build our list-of-quarters subquery into a subquery to produce the most recent quarter's data.

```
SELECT I.QUARTER, I.VENDOR_CATEGORY, I.STANDARD_VENDOR_NAME, SUM(I.SPEND) SPEND
  FROM INFO I
  JOIN (        
    SELECT DISTINCT QUARTER
      FROM INFO
     WHERE QUARTER <= ~~~the most recent quarter~~~
     ORDER BY QUARTER DESC
     LIMIT 0,1
 ) Q ON I.QUARTER=Q.QUARTER
 GROUP BY I.QUARTER, I.VENDOR_CATEGORY, I.STANDARD_VENDOR_NAME
```

This is our basic quarterly lookup building block.  It's pretty obvious at this point that you're going to need your INFO table to have indexes on the QUARTER and VENDOR_CATEGORY columns.

You may want a compound index on both those, or even on (QUARTER, VENDOR_CATEGORY, STANDARD_VENDOR_NAME) all together.  But get things working. Then look at EXPLAIN output. Then try adding other indexes.  It's worth fiddling around with indexes to optimize this building block query before you go any further.

We will need three more of these little subqueries, one for each preceding quarter.  The subqueries are the same as the building block except for `LIMIT 0,1`, `LIMIT 1,1`, `LIMIT 3,1`, and `LIMIT 4,1`.

We also need a master list of all the VENDOR_CATEGORY and STANDARD_VENDOR_NAME combinations we need to display. This query pops out results for any category/vendor combination that showed up once or more in any of the quarters you are considering.

```
SELECT DISTINCT I.VENDOR_CATEGORY, I.STANDARD_VENDOR_NAME
  FROM INFO I
  JOIN (        
    SELECT DISTINCT QUARTER
      FROM INFO
     WHERE QUARTER <= ~~~the most recent quarter~~~
     ORDER BY QUARTER DESC
     LIMIT 0,4
 ) Q ON I.QUARTER=Q.QUARTER
```

Don't do LEFT JOIN in this one or you'll end up with all your category/vendor items including the ones you haven't spent money with in the most recent four quarters.

Now we need to put it all together. Things get absurdly verbose (isn't SQL fun?).  We have to join all this these building blocks together.  Here's the outline of our grand query, with comments to show where the building blocks go.

```
SELECT A.VENDOR_CATEGORY, A.STANDARD_VENDOR_NAME, Q.SPEND, R.SPEND, S.SPEND, T.SPEND
  FROM (
     /* category combinations */
  )A
  LEFT JOIN (
     /* most recent quarter spend */
  )Q ON (           A.VENDOR_CATEGORY=Q.VENDOR_CATEGORY 
                AND A.STANDARD_VENDOR_NAME=Q.STANDARD_VENDOR_NAME)
  LEFT JOIN (
     /* second most recent quarter spend */
  )R ON (           A.VENDOR_CATEGORY=R.VENDOR_CATEGORY
                AND A.STANDARD_VENDOR_NAME=R.STANDARD_VENDOR_NAME)
  LEFT JOIN (
     /* third most recent quarter spend */
  )S ON (           A.VENDOR_CATEGORY=S.VENDOR_CATEGORY
                AND A.STANDARD_VENDOR_NAME=S.STANDARD_VENDOR_NAME)
  LEFT JOIN (
     /* fourth most recent quarter spend */
  )T ON (           A.VENDOR_CATEGORY=T.VENDOR_CATEGORY
                AND A.STANDARD_VENDOR_NAME=T.STANDARD_VENDOR_NAME)
ORDER BY A.VENDOR_CATEGORY, A.STANDARD_VENDOR_NAME
```

I will leave it to you to insert the subqueries into this outline.

You probably have already used something like this to generate your temp table. But if you get it right, you can simply use this big query to generate your report. Unless your info table has gazillions of rows, it will run fairly quickly if you index your tables correctly.

If you DO have gazillions of rows, you probably work for a big company that can spring for a bigger mySQL server with fast disks and multiple gigabytes of RAM. That will also speed things up, especially once you work out the indexing.